# How to prevent from bypassing registration form when the user's inputs are incorrect?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I was trying to make my first registration form and I've been trying to figure out what I did wrong. Whenever I type an incorrect or invalid input or say an invalid username or email, I'm still able to register and have the data sent into my database as long as I've filled out the form. I'm still a beginner so I'm not sure how to properly arrange them or what I'm missing

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
form{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 470px;
    margin-top:150px;
}
label{
     width: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.error{
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])&&isset($_POST['email'])&&isset($_POST['age'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password_hash = md5($password);

    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];


    if(!empty($username)){
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$username)) {
        $usernameErr = " Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }
    if(!empty($password)){
    if(!empty($email)){
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
           $emailErr = " Invalid email"; 
         }
    if(!empty($gender)){
    if(!empty($age)){
        if(strlen($username)>30){
            $error = 'Please ahear to maxlength of fields.';
        } else {


            //MySQL database code goes here

        }


    } else {
        $ageErr = ' Select your age';
    }
    } else {
        $genderErr = ' Select your gender';
    }
    } else {
        $emailErr = ' Enter your email';
    }
    } else {
        $passErr = ' Enter your password';
    }   
    } else {
    $usernameErr = ' Enter your username';
    }
}
?>

        <span class="error"><?php echo $error?></span>
        <br><br>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST" autocomplete="off">   
            <h2>Register</h2>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="50" value="<?php if(isset($username)){echo $username;}?>">
                <span class="error"><?php echo $usernameErr?></span>
                <br><br>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
                <span class="error"><?php echo $passErr?></span>
                <br><br>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="30" value="<?php if(isset($email)){echo $email;}?>">
                <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr?></span>
                <br><br>
            <label>Gender</label>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">Male   
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">Female
                <span class="error"><?php echo $genderErr?></span>
                <br><br>
            <label>Age</label>
                <select name="age" class="age">
                    <option value> </option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29">29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                </select>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $ageErr?></span>
                <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this. There are a few ways to make this more efficient but taking into account the above approach I would at a minimum break up the validation logic by field rather than a giant nested if. So in the example below you set a master validation boolean that will basically say yes submit, or no don't. As each type of field does its validation it will make sure that variable is set to false if anything fails. Then at the end of the script you do a final if statement checking the validation status, if its good to go then do your mysql form submission stuff. If not then continue processing and output the errors. The other thing that changed is your initial if statement ( `if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])&&isset($_POST['email'])&&isset($_POST['age'])){`. You really only need to check that you are attempting to post a form since each field is then validated. Hope this helps!

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

    // make sure that you have posted to the file
    if(count($_POST) > 0){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $password_hash = md5($password);
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];

        // use a boolean value to catch errors
        $validated = true;

            // validate username
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$username)){
            $usernameErr = " Only letters and white space allowed";
            $validated = false;
        } else if(empty($username)){
            $usernameErr = ' Enter your username';
            $validated = false;
        }

            // validate username length
        if(strlen($username)>30){
            $error = 'Please ahear to maxlength of fields.';
        }

            // validate password
        if(empty($password)){
            $passErr = ' Enter your password';
            $validated = false;
        }

            // validate email
        if (!empty($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = " Invalid email";
            $validated = false;
        } else if(empty($email)){
            $emailErr = ' Enter your email';
            $validated = false;
        }


        if(empty($gender)){
            $genderErr = ' Select your gender';
            $validated = false;
        }

        if(empty($age)){
            $ageErr = ' Select your age';
            $validated = false;
        }

        if($validated === true){
            echo 'im here';
                //MySQL database code goes here
        }
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
form{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 470px;
    margin-top:150px;
}
label{
     width: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.error{
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $error?></span>
    <br><br>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <h2>Register</h2>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="50" value="<?php if(isset($username)){echo $username;}?>">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $usernameErr?></span>
            <br><br>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $passErr?></span>
            <br><br>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="30" value="<?php if(isset($email)){echo $email;}?>">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr?></span>
            <br><br>
        <label>Gender</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">Female
            <span class="error"><?php echo $genderErr?></span>
            <br><br>
        <label>Age</label>
            <select name="age" class="age">
                <option value> </option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
            </select>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $ageErr?></span>
            <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```